# cakephp query last seven days

Tags: sql, cakephp

I have function to show most readed articles so I did try condtion 
I want show last most readed last week

```
   $conditions =  array( "Post.created >" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 
> weeks")));
```

the columns in database of created column like this 2011-07-04 05:41:15

but it didn't work well with me

Answer (score 3):

```
$conditions = array("Post.created >" => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-7 days")));
```